# WPF MVVM Pagesize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

i have view with paging, but my window on different resolutions have different size, so i never know how much data i need to ask from wcf service method to fill whole screen, i have tried to put rows one by one in collection and check if ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility of scrobbviewer will become Visible,but it doesnt work that way, also i cant get size of control so i cant even calculate page size. Maybe it's because i do all of there in constructor of new View, and i'm doing this using Catel 3.2.
Is there any simple way to get pagesize?

Comment: Are your items all the same height? Perhaps you could load one item, check its height, then set the # of items to load equal to `(ScrollViewer.ActualHeight / itemHeight) + 1`?

Comment: but how to do this using MVVM pattern? how can i bind ActualHeight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding event to command on LayoutUpdated solved the problem, and yes adding 1 item to measure item height was also helpfull